# CSS Skill Bar Animation on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm looking to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462336/only-play-css-animation-when-scroll-over). I'm using code from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298260/animate-progress-bar-on-scroll) but the answer is never made entirely clear. They are suggested to use [this jquery plugin here](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) but I haven't been able to get it to work. I would go with the first example's code, only, I'm using Foundation 4 and the progress bars are something that come with it and are simpler to create. Also, the animation code provided in the second example is a lot cleaner-- overall, the first example is kinda messy, code heavy, and redundant.

My code is live [here](http://jacquelynchastain.com/test). I'm working with the skill bars in the about section. Before the user gets to this point, the animation should be paused. Once the user scrolls to this part of the page, the animation should play.

EDIT: Also, if you have any suggestions to stop the bars from "breaking" out of their containers when you scale the page (this site is meant to be responsive), I would appreciate that as well.

EDIT2: I've noticed as I've been playing with this that overflow: hidden; on .progress fixes my "breaking" issue.. however, when you resize the window, the sizes stay at what they initialized at. I know realistically users visiting my site likely won't be resizing the window a whole lot, but for employers looking at it, it'll kinda be lame if it doesn't work properly. I'm having this same issue with the grumpy-cat button overlays where it initializes at the first size and doesn't resize the overlay after that. Suggestions to this would be really, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your skill bar is and you know where your screen is at, you only need javascript. (no plugins or weird stuff)

To get the vertical position of your screen it's simple:

```
 window.pageYOffset
```

To get the vertical position of your div, you just need

```
 div.offsetTop
```

In your case, I would give an id to the div that wraps all the skill bars and set a loop (window.requestAnimationFrame https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame ) to check if you're within reach of the div (say, if the difference between the window offset and the div is less than some amount).

If the answer is yes, trigger the animation.

The best way to do the animation is by a css transition. (if you need a good intro to css animations here's a video that i found helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoncDvOfUkk )

You can set css animations from javascript.

The idea is that you would set all your "meter" widths to 0. Then in javascript do something like:

```
 div.style.transition = "width 1s";
 div.style.width = someValue;
```

My recommendation for the value to include in the div is some constant fraction of the "progress" div, as in with % as opposed to em or px. This technique should work. (in case you still have issues, you have a window.requestAnimationFrame loop going on so you can recalculate the values at each timestep... although... beware performance).

The reason you were recommended jQuery is because when you're going to have to update all the divs in order to animate them, just writing $(this).find('.meter') and then addClass('.expand') is so much easier.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hrm... Thank you for the help but I haven't been able to quite figure this out. If you have any more information, send it my way.